# Xamarin MediaPicker saves image on Android 11 but not on Android 10

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am following [Xamarin.Essentials: Media Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android)

I have two Android devices I am using for testing, the device that has android 11 installed takes the picture and saves it fine to the phone, The other device running android 10 takes the picture but doesn't save the photo.

I don't get any errors or warnings. When I step through the code it works as expected

The target framework version on the Android is set to Android 10Q

I tried different ways of creating the path e.g. `AppDataDirectory` / `CacheDirectory`

Like:

`var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory , photo.FileName);`

`var newFile =  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);`

I have tried to create a simple txt file in the same path with no success.

Added the CopyToAsync in a try method, it does not throw an exception.

```
                try
                {
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw;
                }
```

My question is what am I doing wrong? The code works perfectly fine on one device seemingly fine on another but does not actually execute.

Since I don't get errors or warnings what would be a good approach to debug this?

Comment: Please post enough code to illustrate the problem, not just small snippets.  How are you determining the file is not saved?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger on both devices?

Comment: Did you try to create a file with the path your save the image on the android 10? You can alse try to debug to check if the code about saving the image hit or not.